# Customizing Recent Order Customer dashboard

Tags: orders, dashboard

I'm trying to customize the Customer Dashboard recent order table. Currently, it is only showing Order ID, Date , Ship to, order total and status.

I'm trying to replace Ship to into product name. Below is my attempt. I'm getting this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductName() on a non-object" I'm very new in magento development. Hope you guys can help.

**recent.phtml**

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="number"><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
                <th class="date"><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
               <?php /** <th class="ship"><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th> **/ ?>
                <th class="ship"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
                <th class="total"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
                <th class="status"><?php echo $this->__('Status') ?></th>
                <th class="view">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="number"><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                    <td class="date"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
                   <?php /** <td class="ship"><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td> **/?>
                    <td class="ship"><?php echo $this->getProduct()->getProductName();  ?></td>

                    <td class="total"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                    <td class="status"><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
                    <td class="a-center view">
                        <span class="nobr">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                            <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
```

**Edits**

Still not showing anything. Please help

```
<tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="number"><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                    <td class="date"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
                    <?php /** <td class="ship"><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>**/?>
                    <?php 
                    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_order->getRealOrderId());
                    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
                    $items = $order->getAllItems();
                    foreach($items as $item){
                        $name = $item->getProductName();
                    }
                    ?>
                    <td class="ship"><?php echo $name ?></td>               
                    <td class="total"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                    <td class="status"><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
                    <td class="a-center view">
                        <span class="nobr">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                            <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProductName()`  is `sales_order_item function which is give products name of a sales item.`

In `recent don't showing order products ids`. it only show order if you want to get order products ids then you need load order

```
     $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_order->getRealOrderId());

     $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
   // OR

    $items = $order->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $item){
            $name = $item->getName();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried implementing your code, but doesnt seem to work either

Comment: ckd now.It is my mistake