# My account page (recent.phtml)

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, sales-order, customer-account, reorder

I have been trying to figure out how reorder and my account pages are working.

I have a My Account page which shows '**Recent orders**', showing a table that includes Order number, Date, Ship to, Total price, and Status. Also, there is a last column with "**See order**" and "**Reorder**" buttons.

Indeed, I think that the code for this Recent Orders is in **recent.phml** , which can be found at `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\sales\order`. However, I've tried to modify the code in this file, but I obtain no results, even if I delete Magento's and browser's cache. I tried to do the same as in [Customizing Recent Order Customer dashboard](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36583/customizing-recent-order-customer-dashboard), but still I see no effects in my webpage.

Here's my code in recent.phtml, after modifying it as in the post I linked:

```
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>
<div class="box-head">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Recent Orders') ?></h2>
    <?php if( sizeof($_orders->getItems()) > 0 ): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/history') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View All') ?></a><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if( sizeof($_orders->getItems()) > 0 ): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
<col width="1" />
<col width="1" />
<col />
<col width="1" />
<col width="1" />
<col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TextChanged<?php //echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <!--<th><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>-->
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Status') ?></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td> -->

                <?php
                     $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_order->getRealOrderId());

                    $items = $order->getAllItems();
                    foreach($items as $item){
                    $name = $item->getName();
                }
                ?>

                <td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                <td><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
                <td class="a-center">
                    <span class="nobr">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                        <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table')</script>
<?php else: ?>
<p><?php echo $this->__('You have placed no orders.'); ?></p>
```

I would like to know how can I modify this Recent Orders page. Is this the correct file? Any ideas or comments will be much appreciated :-)

Comment: are u edit your theme file ?

Comment: Okay that was it...  I'm pretty new to Magento. Thanks! If you want to you can add an answer, I know it's simple but then I can mark it as correct. I found the file to modify under \app\design\frontend\default\custom_theme\template\sales\order. I also would like to ask, should i always look into custom_theme\template when trying to modify frontend behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must need to add file in your theme with same folder structure.

if your package default then file inside default/default work and other package then must inside your theme or base/default but in change base/default not good option during upgrade that will lost.